# How can I show a div if checkbox is ticked on Sharepoint designer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, asp-classic

I don't know why this code won't work but when I check the checkbox it won't work. The div just remains hidden. I have done this before but this time it won't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Checkboxes</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
        var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
        if (checked) {
           $('.other').show();             
        } else {
            $('.other').hide();
        }
    });        
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div name="main">

    <input type="checkbox" /> If this is checked display div
</div>
<div class='other' name='other' title='other' style='display:none;'>  
<h2>test</h2>
<input></input>
<input></input>
<input></input>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is **no attribute** `checked` in checkbox. So it is returning **undefined**.You can directly access the property by `this.checked`.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
            var checked = this.checked;
            if (checked) {
               $('.other').show();             
            } else {
                $('.other').hide();
            }
        });        
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Had a bit of a stupid moment there.

Answer (score 0):

[**CHECK THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/jz3ek3to/):

you are using `attr` that returns `undefined`

```
  var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
    if (checked) {    //here checked is not a boolean
```

Always remember

`.prop('checked')` returns **boolean**

So use `.prop()` . Rest is fine .

Hope it help :)

Comment: I've ticked the other answer but you're both right so thank you. I'd upvote if I had sufficient reputation!

Comment: Still you can upvote . That's not matter with the reputation i guess @KieranHanna

Comment: Not with this brand new account. I need 15 rep apparently! I may come back when I have enough